# I uploaded an image here and it shows up called "[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bG06.png", is that right?

Tags: support, images

I took a screenshot of my desktop image that I uploaded to here. It is a screen shot of the image on my desktop that I wanted to attach the first time. Why is it showing up as a Imgur.com website?

[image]

The Screen Shot 2018 10..AM that you see here on my desktop is what I uploaded on here to ask a question, when it uploaded it looked like what you see just above this.
`[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKl8X.png`
Why is it naming it that and why is it a website? I think it should just be like the image I took the second time the one attached on here now so I can show you that the first time attachment seems strange. Is it?

Comment: see [formatting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [editing help](https://apple.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for an explanation how you can "layout"  your post. There is no "what you see is what you get" . Use the preview under the post for that. Do know this post belongs on the meta site.

Comment: I wanted to ask a question about automator, because I don't use but I see so much going on in the folder. So I took a screen shot of it and uploaded it. It was on my desktop. I don't understand that is showed up as a webpage link using i.stack.imgur.com.  Are all my screenshots being directed to a Imgur website? How can I find out?

Comment: Yes, all image uploads will be stored on the private instance of Stack Exchange at imgur their servers. This is how the site works.

Comment: oh, ok thank you

Answer (score 5):

Nothing fancy going on; this is Stack Exchange's 'native' [image upload support](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/). We have our 'private' channel on Imgur; that's why there's a `stack` in the URL.

To actually show your image, you have to use image markdown like `![<image description for screen readers>][1]`. This is automatically inserted when you use the Stack Exchange image uploader; from your screenshot it looks like you've edited it out. You could also just try again to upload your image; the system will automatically remove the obsolete link.